# How to get name of TextView object from an TextView object

Tags: java, android, textview

I am trying to get name of the TextView object which is not yet Initialized.

In MainActivity class

```
TextView =varTextView1,varTextView2,varTextView3;
TextView textViewArray [];
```

In function Array Init ;-

```
 textViewArray = new TextView[] {varTextView1,varTextView2,varTextView3};
```

In another function :-

```
String s;
s = textViewArray[0].toString();
```

Tried with

```
.getTransitionName();
```

Error:-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.widget.TextView.toString()' on a null object reference
```

No Error on compile but on Run-time.
Searched on the net But no luck
Can anyone please help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510#218510

Comment: @dave But here after referencing I'm using it.

Comment: @dave  Also now i tried with 'TextView textViewArray [] = new TextView[] {varTextView1,varTextView2,varTextView3}' .Still getting the same error.could you please help......

Comment: That's the problem, you're referencing a null pointer. That's why you get a Null Pointer Exception. You need to wait until it's initialized before you reference it

Comment: Ok i got your point actually  I'm just Initializing the array but not the object inside it.thnx....

Answer (score 0):

The variables of the type *TextView* that you created in the first line of the posted code are just that, variables of the type *TextView*. They aren't actual objects. In Java, a variable of a certain class type can **reference** instances (objects) of that class, but they are not the object themselves.

In this context, since you didn't specify an object for your variables of the type *TextView* to reference to (creating, for example, a new one with the "*new*" operator, like *new TextView()*) a java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown, meaning that you tried to call a method on a *null object reference*.

I hope my explanation helps you. See ya!